# Caching the restricted cookie block globally (instead of store view): how to solve

Tags: cookie, blocks

We are trying to move the restricted cookie store notice to the header block in page/html/header.phtml just above `<div class="header-container">`. This block should be storeview specific.

**Problem:** The problem now is that the first time the block is opened that it sticks to all storeviews (always the same). But they need to be different per store language.

We tried adding a cache tag like below, but this doesn seem to solve it...

Any ideas how to solve this?

```
class Mage_Page_Block_Html_CookieNotice extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{

    protected function _construct() {
        $this->addData(array(
        'cache_lifetime' => 3600,
        'cache_tags'     => array(Mage_Core_Model_Store::CACHE_TAG, Mage_Cms_Model_Block::CACHE_TAG),
        'cache_key'      => 'COOKIE_RESTRICT_BLOCK' . Mage::app()->getStore()->getId(),
        ));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not explain, how you move it, but this sounds like th parent block is cached globally. Adjusting cache settings for a child block does not affect the parent block.